# android transparent picture

Tags: android, transparency, image

do you know how to make a certain part of a picture (jpg) semitransparent, like in the attached image?[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JPEG doesn't support transparency. Can you use a 32-bit PNG instead?

If you have an existing image that you want to apply some transparency pattern to, you will need to create a Bitmap object in code, draw your image, then set some flags to allow you to draw the transparency levels over it, a bit like a Photoshop layer mask. I did a search for Android alpha masking, and found this [blog post](http://nerdposts.blogspot.com/2010/05/android-alpha-masking.html).

Comment: yes, I can use, but I must not alterate the image. I read the image from the file and I create a bitmap and put it in an image view. I must create that gradient, because it doesn't exists.

Comment: Added some info on custom alpha masking.

Answer (score 2):

Just use a PNG image instead. Problem solved :)

Comment: yes, I can use, but I must not alterate the image. I read the image from the file and I create a bitmap and put it in an image view. I must create that gradient, because it doesn't exists.

Answer (score 0):

Err - I may be utterly confused here, but why not just use `setAlpha(int alpha)` on the inflated ImageView?

That seems to work fine on a .jpg for me.

Or is it only part of the image that should be transparent? Hard to see the 'sample image'.

Comment: it is only for the upper part of the image